# Store string variables from PyQt4 Text Box

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I have created a small uic file with qt Designer in order to build a small gui using PyQt4. One of the elements of that gui is a simple textbox, where I set a string value (textbox is called RiskDate_Box). After setting this value in the GUI, I want to use it as a string variable in the following code (not seen here) . My problem is, that I am not able to store it, in the code seen below I tried it in two different ways ( store it as Riskdate1 and Riskdate2). After compiling the code, bothvariables are empty and not equal to the value I set in the GUI, e.g. '12.08.2012'. However, if I compile the script and after that only compile

```
Riskdate2=window.RiskDate_Box.toPlainText()
```

then the Riskdate set in the Gui is correctly assigned to the variable 'Riskdate2' as a string. Would be great if someone could help me with that issue.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic            
import sys

# Gui Code


qtCreatorFile = "untitled.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("untitled.ui", self)              
        self.show() 
        self.RiskDate=self.RiskDate_Box.toPlainText()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app=QtGui.QApplication.instance()
   app=0
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
   window = MyWindow()
    #Try 1 to store variable
    Riskdate1=window.RiskDate
    # Try 2 to store variable
    Riskdate2=window.RiskDate_Box.toPlainText()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: How do you set value(text) into RiskDate_Box? programmatically or you type it after dialog shows?

Comment: I Type it after the dialog shows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to send s signal when text in your QPlainTextEdit is changed

> void QPlainTextEdit::textChanged()
>
> > This signal is emitted whenever the document's content changes; for example, when text is inserted or deleted, or when formatting is applied.

you need to do something like:

```
    self.RiskDate_Box.textChanged.connect(self.get_text)
    self.show() 

def get_text(self):
    self.RiskDate = self.RiskDate_Box.toPlainText())
    print (self.RiskDate)
```

[image]